# If file does not contain string powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to run a powershell command only if a certain string does not exist in a certain file.

This is my script

```
$pattern='<!--add key="MaxNumCycles" value="40"/-->'
$textToAdd=$pattern + '

    <!--RerunMode: 1 write to DB, 2 write to DB and add to RUN export/-->
    <add key="RerunMode" value="0"/>'

$filename="C\temp\Software.exe.config"

[IO.File]::ReadAllText($filename).Replace($pattern,$textToAdd) | Set-Content $filename -Force
```

If the `$textToAdd` string is not in $`filename` then I want to run this script. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simple enough, you just read the text in, pipe to `Where`, and perform the replace and `Set-Content` in a `ForEach` block.

```
$pattern='<!--add key="MaxNumCycles" value="40"/-->'
$textToAdd=$pattern + '

    <!--RerunMode: 1 write to DB, 2 write to DB and add to RUN export/-->
    <add key="RerunMode" value="0"/>'

$filename="C\temp\Software.exe.config"

[IO.File]::ReadAllText($filename)| Where{$_ -notlike "*$texttoadd*"} | ForEach{$_.Replace($pattern,$textToAdd) | Set-Content $filename -Force}
```